# Swift - Use dictionary to pass data to params

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I'm trying to pass some datas in my parameters to send to a server. But I'm facing some difficulties to build the params.

I have tried to loop through the array to add the dictionary which consists of the mobile and name but I'm not sure on how to build it properly as it return only first element of the array. I don't know how to append everything in the array.

```
     var parameters: [String: Any] = ["invitations": [
            ["mobile": "1234567",
            "name": "John1"]
            ]
        ]

        for (item1, item2) in zip(arrName, arrNumber){
            parameters = ["invitations": [
                "mobile" : "\(item2)",
                "name" : "\(item1)"]
            ]

        }
```

This is the JSON I'm trying to build in the params.

```
{
    "invitations": [ 
        {
          "mobile": "1234456",
          "name": "Paul"
        },
        {
          "mobile": "1234456",
          "name": "Paul1"
        },
        {
          "mobile": "1234456",
          "name": "Paul2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You are using alamofire ?

Comment: No I'm not using any libraries

Comment: Have you considered using `Codable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let arr = zip(arrNumber,arrName).map { ["mobile":$0,"name":$1] }
var parameters: [String: Any] = ["invitations": arr]
print(parameters)//["invitations": [["name": "Paul", "mobile": "1234456"], ["name": "Paul1", "mobile": "1234456"], ["name": "Paul2", "mobile": "1234456"]]]
do {
    let json = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted)
    let convertedString = String(data: json, encoding: .utf8) 
    print(convertedString)

} catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

> {   "invitations": [
>       {
>         "name": "Paul",
>         "mobile": "1234456"
>       },
>       {
>         "name": "Paul1",
>         "mobile": "1234456"
>       },
>       {
>         "name": "Paul2",
>         "mobile": "1234456"
>       }   ] }